# Encrypt existing SSH key

Tags: encryption, ssh

I've created an RSA keypair for ssh access to a remote server. This all works. When creating the keypair, I didn't enter a password. Now I would like to encrypt the key, secure it with a password.

Is that possible, and if so how can I do that?

**How can I encrypt an existing ssh key with a password?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use this command: `ssh-keygen -o -p -f keyfile`

[Changing the private key's passphrase without changing the key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Changing_the_private_key's_passphrase_without_changing_the_key)

Comment: That's right. You can also modify passphrases later using the same `-p`.

Comment: Note `-o` for new format only works since 6.5 released 2014-01 and is no longer needed (now default) since 7.8 released 2018-08 (in both cases distros often don't take new version immediately).

Comment: For quick reference: `-o` uses a more secure/less compatible key format that requires 6.5 or later; `-p` does a password change rather than generate a key; `-f keyfile` specifies the keyfile to modify, otherwise it will ask you for a filename when you run it.  (It will overwrite whatever file you give it.)